# Run 2 different application with one single domain nginx proxy

Tags: nginx

I have 2 application running with single domain
say www.abc.com is running magento application and i want www.abc.com/pqr should run another laravel application.
I tried to use nginx proxy setting  the Sample nginx files looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80

    root /var/www/magento/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name local.abc.com;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /pqr/ {
            #this is laravel application
            proxy_pass http://local.pqr.com/;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For running two application one a single server you need two instance of that server, in each instance you can specify the configuration related to that particular application.
In this above you are not keeping your second application config details inside the server, so your second application is not having any instance of server.
Try to create a new instance or keep second application config details inside the server.
It might work for you.